# DynamoDBTypeConverter for DynamoDB document field without annotations

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have some entries in DynamoDB, which have an field as follows, in DynamoDB document format:

`{ "foo" : { "N" : "45" }, "bar" : { "N" : "12" }}`

I've got a Java class representing the document type:

```
public class FooBar {
  private final int foo;
  private final int bar;

  public FooBar(
      int foo,
      int bar
  ) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public int getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }

  public int getBar() {
    return bar;
  }
}
```

I'd like to use a [DynamoDB mapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) to get and put rows to the table (the intermediate class representing the entire row is omitted for brevity). I don't want to add the DynamoDB annotations (`@DynamoDBDocument`, `@DynamoDBAttribute` etc) to the `FooBar` class  as they require a zero-argument constructor and setter methods but this should be an immutable data object.

Therefore, I'd like to use a [DynamoDBTypeConverter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverter.html) (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html)) to write my own conversion, but I cannot find a suitable 'source' type (to replace `[?]`):

```
class FooBarConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<[?], FooBar> {
  @Override
  public [?] convert(FooBar object) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public FooBar unconvert([?] object) {
    ...
  }
}
```

- Map, which would seem the most natural, fails with `DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted`
- String, which would seem to be a reasonable default, doesn't error but the string supplied to the `convert()` method is always empty
- Object, which would seem to be a catch-all, isn't supported by Dynamo and fails with `DynamoDBMappingException: could not resolve type of class FooBarConverter`

If we regard both the Java class and the storage format as being unmodifiable, what solution is there?

Comment: Use `@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = FooBarConverter.class)` to the getter of the column you want to give this converter.

Comment: Also use import statement to import `FooBarConverter` in POJO.

Comment: Check here ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992305/dynamodb-mapper-annotation-for-object-which-has-list-of-another-object

Comment: In `DynamoDBTypeConverter<[?], FooBar>`, ? should be something, for example String. Code your logic in convert and unconvert to get desired json to object and object to json.

Comment: Use N.N is DynamoDB type -> N (number type)

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1552

Comment: @prem30488 Thanks for your help, but I don't think you've understood the question properly, and I don't think that any of your comments help with the problem. Please could you delete them if you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found an appropriate type to use for the source - [`AttributeValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/AttributeValue.html). Here's the converter:

```
public class FooBarConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<AttributeValue, FooBar> {
  @Override
  public AttributeValue convert(FooBar object) {
    return new AttributeValue()
        .addMEntry("foo", new AttributeValue().withN(Integer.toString(object.getFoo())))
        .addMEntry("bar", new AttributeValue().withN(Integer.toString(object.getBar())));
  }

  @Override
  public FooBar unconvert(AttributeValue object) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> objectM = object.getM();
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(objectM.get("foo").getN());
    int bar = Integer.parseInt(objectM.get("bar").getN());
    return new FooBar(foo, bar);
  }
}
```

Also, a class to represent the whole row in Dynamo:

```
public class FooBarRow {
  private String key;
  private FooBar fooBar;

  public FooBarRow(
      String key,
      FooBar fooBar
  ) {
    this.key = key;
    this.fooBar = fooBar;
  }

  public FooBarRow() {
  }

  @DynamoDBHashKey
  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = FooBarConverter.class)
  public FooBar getFooBar() {
    return fooBar;
  }

  public void setFooBar(FooBar fooBar) {
    this.fooBar = fooBar;
  }
}
```

Now, saving and loading `FooBarRow` instances using a `DynamoDBMapper` works perfectly.

```
public class FooBarMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build(),
        DynamoDBMapperConfig
            .builder()
            .withTableNameOverride(new DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride("foobar"))
            .build()
    );

    mapper.save(new FooBarRow("foobar1", new FooBar(123, 4)));

    mapper.load(FooBarRow.class, "foobar1").getFooBar();
  }
}
```

Comment: I love you. Great writeup.

Comment: Thanks! Not only did you help me solve my problem by pointing out what I was missing, but your write-up was clear and concise. #PaulForPresident